# Яндекс.Карты некорректно работают с shadowDOM

Tags: yandex-maps-api, polymer

Передаю в конструктор карты ссылку на контейнер для карты.
Карта рисуется над всем содержимым страницы и как бы перекрывает все окно.

```
this.mapDiv = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#map");
var map = new ymaps.Map(this.mapDiv, {
        center: [55.76, 37.64], 
        zoom: 7
});
```

[image: a]

Comment: Добрый день, можно пожалуйста пример сайта или пример собранный на jsfiddle где можно увидеть проблему?

Comment: Добрый день! Пример на Google Polymer https://jsfiddle.net/c12o3jaf/21/

Answer (score 1):

Я решил так, создал контейнер

```
    <div id="mapSlot" class="container">
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
    </div>
```

и задал им стили

```
 #map {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .container {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            position: relative;
        }
```

Но считать это решением я бы не стал, ибо помимо этого в дебаг моде будет ошибка
 "Uncaught Error: util.dom.element.html: попытка переопределить innerHTML у элемента, не добавленного в документ", а если выставить обычный режим то нет возможности разместить маркеры, и.т.д.
      В случае если добавлять div в корневой документ

```
 document.body.appendChild(this.$.map);
```

всё работает нормально, но как только yandex maps получает референс на объект из ShadowDom начинаются проблемы.